# syntax error when joining tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to merge multiple tables. This is how I am doing it:

```
CREATE TABLE big3 AS SELECT * 
FROM trainSearchStream a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SearchInfo b ON b.SearchID=a.SearchID LIMIT 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN AdsInfo c ON c.AdID=a.AdID LIMIT 3;
```

However, I get this error:

> Error: near "LEFT": syntax error

Comment: Only one LIMIT allowed, at the end.

Comment: You are trying to limit SearchInfo and AdsInfo to a maximum of three matches each? So when you find four SearchInfos for one trainSearchStream, you take three of them, no matter which? Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ideally I would want to merge the whole tables. but because my tables are huge and they might take >30 mins for each join I use limit to test my code lines first. @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jarlh already mentioned, there can be only one LIMIT per select statement.

So this is forbidden:

```
select *
from a limit 5
join b limit 6 an a.x = b.x;
```

But this would be allowed:

```
select *
from (select * from a limit 5) alim
join (select * from b limit 6) blim on alim.x = blim.x;
```

As you simply want to test your query however, I'd suggest, you take a sample from trainSearchStream to test it. The modulo operator % is great for taking samples:

```
CREATE TABLE big3 AS SELECT * 
FROM (select * from trainSearchStream where searchid % 12345 = 6789) a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SearchInfo b ON b.SearchID = a.SearchID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AdsInfo c ON c.AdID = a.AdID;
```

Choose whatever numbers you like for the modulo operation. Above statement divides your trainSearchStream count by about 12345 (provided the IDs are evenly spread).